# BIC selection yields much smaller model than AIC - can I use the likelihood ratio test to compare?

Tags: model-selection, aic, likelihood-ratio, bic, deviance

I'm trying to model the data (not make predictions) and am NOT using lasso for this, just want to know if my plan is somewhat reasonable here:

I'm modelling for a "yes/no" response variable, so I used logistic regression and stepwiseAIC for variable selection. The results gives me 13 parameters: 8 covariates with 5 interaction terms (several parameters are not significant on their own but have a significant interaction).

When I instead used stepwise based on BIC criteria, I only got two covariates and their interaction. Much simpler of course, but the deviance increased quite a bit. Since all the parameters in the small model were also in the large one, I considered the small one to be nested, so I did the deviance test (likelihood ratio test) and it gave me a p-value of nearly 0, indicating that the larger model is better.

Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using variable selection procedures like minimizing AIC or BIC impacts p-values of subsequent hypothesis tests (as well as impacting other things such as bias of parameter estimates and standard errors). Testing a hypothesis based on two different model selection procedures doesn't have the nominal properties; finding statistical significance for a difference of the two models is neither surprising nor necessarily informative about the relative worth of the two models.

BIC and AIC are based on different assumptions about the situation; the two aren't consistent with each other -- if $n>7$ then using BIC to select a model will always penalize larger models more harshly than AIC.

[If you use AIC to do 1 variable-at-a-time stepwise selection, it's equivalent to doing ordinary stepwise model selection based on a significance level of 15.7%; BIC would correspond to reducing the significance level with larger sample size.]

If you're going to then use hypothesis testing to choose between them, you're essentially falling back on p-values for variable selection. AIC works out "better" one way; BIC a different way, and the likelihood ratio test a different way a again.

I don't think there's a good argument for the procedure you have adopted.

Comment: Okay - so no deviance test for comparing the AIC model to BIC model. Follow up question - I can use it to compare two BIC models, correct? n=800 in this case, and direction=both gave me a 3-term model compared to 8 for direction = back, so I'm wondering if I can use it for such a case...

Comment: i. correct -- you select a criterion and use that criterion. ii. No, you don't compare nested models selected via BIC or AIC using a significance test. You can just compare BIC (or if you prefer, compare AIC).

Comment: @Glen_b, Does it make sense if I use LRT for nested model selection, and BIC for non-nested model selection? For example, I would like to know the best predictor among weight/BMI/height for breast cancer risk, I fitted them individually and pairwise. Then I compared the weight-only/BMI-only/height-only models based on BIC, and the pairwise combined model with the weight-only/BMI-only/height-only models based on LRT.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes. The likelihood ratio test is used to test the difference in goodness-of-fit between two models, and what you described would be an appropriate use of this test. [This page](http://warnercnr.colostate.edu/~gwhite/fw663/LikelihoodRatioTests.PDF) provides some additional detail on using likelihood ratio tests on nested models.

Using BIC to perform model selection is often too restrictive when your dataset is large. This *might* be what's happening for you; I don't know how many observations you have. The reason is because of the way AIC vs. BIC are calculated:

AIC = 2d - 2ln⁡(L) , where d is the number of parameters.

BIC = ln(n)d - 2ln(L) , where n is the number of observations and d is the number of parameters.

As we can see, the only difference in the BIC formula is that the coefficient in front of d changed from 2 to ln(n), meaning that BIC places a much higher penalty on the model if your dataset is large, thus favoring simpler models.

You also said that you're not interested in prediction, just modeling the data. So I won't go too much into detail regarding performing cross-validation on training vs. testing sets. But I do stress that this is very important; a more complex model will *always* fit the training data better, but the complexity might lead to overfitting when you try to apply the model elsewhere.